# How to link multiple kml in google map

Tags: google-maps, kml

I need to load many more kml files like this. How can i do so?

```
<script>
  var map;
  var src = 'https://sites.google.com/site/pdbkml/pdbmap/pdb.kmz';
```

Or is there any way to merge multiple kmls into one?

Comment: The URL doesn't work just to tell you

Comment: What are you doing with that link? How are you "loading" it? Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue. You can certainly load multiple KmlLayers on a Google Maps JavaScript API Map, but it isn't clear what you are doing.

Comment: i have several kml files i need to show on google map. here i just loaded one of them by " var src = 'https://sites.google.com/site/pdbkml/pdbmap/pdb.kmz';" and it's working. How can i load all of them? if i can not add more kmls, how can i marge all the kmls into one kml?

Comment: i mean i am able to show pdb.kmz on top of google map. but i have many more layers. how can i show all of them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display multiple KML files on one map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30608878/how-to-display-multiple-kml-files-on-one-map)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use more kmlLayer

```
    function initMap() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 11,
        center: {lat: 45.1, lng: 12.1}
      });

      var kmlLayer1 = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
        url: 'http://your_domain/your_path/yourkml1.kml',
        map: map
      });

      var kmlLayer2 = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
        url: 'http://your_domain/your_path/yourkml2.kml',
        map: map
      });
      var kmlLayer3 = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
        url: 'http://your_domain/your_path/yourkml3.kml',
        map: map
      });


    }
  </script>
```

Comment: I have added layers under my previous code like this, layers are coming... but position is not working.... it's showing different position different times.. can you help please?

Comment: @user6086089   .i suggest you of post a specific new question properly documented with the related  code .. so is possible evalute your actual problem ..

Comment: can you please tell me what is the default view place of the code you provided? or how can i add marker in there?

Comment: @user6086089   . try google   "google maps kmllayer"   you can find some sample ..

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit of about 20 kml layers you can display depending upon the length of the URL to each KML file. If you exceed the limit no kml files will display and you get a js error