# How can I show multiple KML URLs in Google Map Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, kml

I have developed an app which displays a single KML URL on a Google Map. Now I want to extend it so it will show multiple KMLs.

How should I approach this? Is there an API I can use?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30608878/how-to-display-multiple-kml-files-on-one-map , It may help you.

Comment: Thanks For that I working on native app,this code is working on Google map V3 not v2

Comment: If your running native you should call your procedure that loads the kml for each url.

Comment: Which procedure to follow?? I have loaded single Kml url on google map but multiple how??

Comment: Post the code where you loaded one KML. It will help to better understand your issue.